# Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/foldername'

Tags: meteor, build, permissions, mkdir

While trying to deploy my meteor app using:

```
meteor build /foldername --mobile-settings settings.json --server=https://appname.herokuapp.com/
```

I get this error:

```
/Users/username/.meteor/packages/less/.2.7.9.1rcbr4q++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLessBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/foldername'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:794:18)
    at Object.wrapper [as mkdir] (/tools/fs/files.js:1586:35)
    at Object.files.mkdir_p (/tools/fs/files.js:445:11)
    at buildCommand (/tools/cli/commands.js:977:11)
    at Command.func (/tools/cli/commands.js:831:12)
    at /tools/cli/main.js:1483:23
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You don't have the permission to create a folder, maybe use root user to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a permission issue. you have to be a super user before run your code. or else

> sudo meteor build /foldername --mobile-settings settings.json
>   --server=https://appname.herokuapp.com/

use the above code in your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`mobile-settings` and `server` aren't described in the [doc](http://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorbuild).

You are trying to create a bundle in / wihout root rights.
Try `meteor build ../foldername`